# How to confirm the number of connections in Oracle 12C?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Looks like this is a contentious topic but I don't seem to find any concrete answers on this.

*V$Session* table only lists the active sessions whereas connection pool implementations define limits with connection numbers.

Is there any way to get the number of active connections to an Oracle Database?

Comment: `v$session` is probably what you are looking for. I gives you the list of all sessions currently connected to the database. What makes you think that this is not what you need?

Comment: Define "active connections".  `v$session` lists all sessions whether they are active or inactive (the `status` column, in fact, has values of ACTIVE or INACTIVE) according to Oracle's definition where a session is active if a user is executing a SQL statement.  In a normal three-tier environment, most sessions are inactive most of the time under Oracle's definition because they are sitting in a connection pool waiting to be allocated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *instantaneous* active sessions can be obtained from V$SESSION where STATUS column is ACTIVE.

You perhaps are more interested in the average active sessions over time. This is tracked directly in the database in the V$SYSMETRIC_HISTORY view, under the metric (unsurprisingly) called: Average Active Sessions

Hope this helps